# Why is `splice(@_, 0, shift)` safe?

Tags: perl, parameter-passing, evaluation

The perl 5.18.2 documentation of `splice` has this example:

```perl
my(@a) = splice(@_,0,shift);
my(@b) = splice(@_,0,shift);
```

And I wonder:
If `@_` is evaluated before the `shift` there would be one item too much for the result to be correct.
So conceptually the `shift` must be performed first.
However in C they teach you that you should never rely on a specific order of evaluation of actual parameters (`shift` modifies `@_`).

So is that code only working because `@_` is passed as a reference (to be able to change it), and the `shift` being evaluated before `splice` can access `@_`?

### A Bit of History

I found the example goes some way back to 1996 (at least) and the book (page 219; a comment on page 535 suggests it may even come along from Perl 4):

> WALL, Larry, Tom CHRISTIANSEN und Randal L. SCHWARTZ, 1996. Programming Perl. 2. Sebastopol, CA 95472, U.S.A.: O’Reilly & Associates, Inc. ISBN 1-56592-149-6

Comment: I don't see that snippet in [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice).

Comment: @choroba It is in one of the earlier versions of that page: https://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.4/functions/splice and back.

Comment: Yes, and [here](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/13321) the discussion that led to the change.

Comment: it's a weird way to write things, but you've correctly understood how this works – `splice(@arr, ...)` doesn't take the array by value but effectively by reference. Think of splice having a `(\@;$$@)` prototype. In the Perldoc, you can see this because splice is documented as taking an ARRAY (by-ref), not a LIST (by-value).

Comment: @choroba From the link provided it seems that example code is a "Mr. Wall original" (and thus may not be changed) ;-) Well, it probably inspires thinking, but it's not the best example for programming style IMHO.

Comment: I'd say that the above comments settle it, specially when one reads through the p5p discussion linked by choroba (thanks, interesting :).  Just to add a possibly useful tidbit: the prototype of `splice` (that amon's comment nicely uses) is found by `prototype "CORE::splice"` --> `+;$$@`.  Here `+` means either `\@` or `\%` (array or hash name)

Answer (score 3):

Because `@_` itself is being passed to `splice` (rather than being flattened or copied) because `splice` is expected to modify it.

---

With a normal subroutine, an array in the argument list would get flattened. But `splice` is an operator, so it's not limited to the behaviour of subroutines.

Perl provides the array to `splice` instead. And not a copy of it. The array itself is placed on the stack. This allows it to be modified, and it's more efficient as a bonus.

(In C terms, "the array" is a pointer. All Perl variables are pointers. The fact that only pointers are being exchanged under the hood is why Perl exhibits pass-by-reference semantics.)

Perl evaluates lists from left to right, so `@_` is placed on the stack, then `0` is placed on the stack, then `shift` is evaluated modifying `@_` and placing the removed value on the stack.

It doesn't matter that `@_` is modified when it's found on the stack. As long as these things happen before the `splice` is performed — and they are — it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I find these phrases rather confusing (after having changed a few others): "the array itself is placed on the stack" (when a reference is conceptually passed), "All Perl variables are pointers." (I'm afraid that would confuse most people thinking of `$a = $b`). Also the order of evaluation of the actual parameters is not relevant; what is important is the fact that parameters are evaluated *before* the function code is run (that is the array `@_` "had been shifted already").  
(continues on next comment)

Comment: Also mentioning "the stack" and "found on the stack" probably confuses most people (even when it's the internal mechanism being used). -- Maybe you want to "touch up the answer a bit".

Comment: @U. Windl. Your edits were reverted since they were all incorrect: 1) Passing by reference is not the same thing as passing a reference. 2) "Sub" wasn't a reference to the keyword but short for subroutine. 3) There's no array reference. Splice does not receive an array reference.

Comment: Re "*Also mentioning "the stack" and "found on the stack" probably confuses most*", The simple explanation is above the break. It's basically exactly the same, minus the parts that must necessarily mention the stack.

Comment: My attempt to improve your answer may be wrong in your opinion, but in my opinion the answer is really hard to understand as you seem to refer to Perl implementation details (which seem to use phrases very uncommon to *users* of Perl). So IMHO either make the answer easier to understand by changing some phrases, or explain even more the fine differences of "references being passed" and "being passed by reference". Maybe I just lack basic understanding of `@_`, in which case you are free ad add another reference. Don't get me wrong: It's all to make *others* happy, too.

Comment: Re "*My attempt to improve your answer may be wrong in your opinion*", It wasn't a question of opinion. Your edits claimed things which were objectively wrong.

Comment: Re "*you seem to refer to Perl implementation detail*", Well yeah. The question is asking about implementation details. So of course I explained implementation details.

Comment: Re "*explain even more the fine differences of "references being passed" and "being passed by reference"*", The answer does not contain either of those sentences. Passing by reference is mentioned, but only in a footnote. Feel free to ignore the footnote.

Comment: Re "*Maybe I just lack basic understanding of @_*", There's nothing special about `@_`. The answer is the same regardless of the array used.

Comment: Re "*make the answer easier to understand*" What do you not understand? Maybe you need to write a your own version of `splice` and `shift` which take an array reference. You'll see `mysplice( \@a, 0, myshift( \@a ) )` works the same way as `splice( @a, 0, shift( @a  ) )`. With `splice` and `shift`, the array itself is passed instead of an reference to it, but the reason they work the same is the same: the array isn't flattened or copied.